# Styled Components Conditional Styling with href value

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm working on `Gatsby` Blog with `React`.

I want to style a tag with specific `href` value with Styled Components like this

To style this a tag
a `href="/asdasdasd"/`

this was What I thought

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    a[href==${props=>props.hrefvalue}]{         //hrefvalue == /asdasdasd
         color: #333; 
    }
`
```

I could apply with React, but want to know how to apply this feature with styled components

Comment: Should work, any codesandbox example?

Answer (score 0):

ckeck this :

style.js file :

```
const StyledLink = Styled.a`

    color:${props=>props.href === "#" ? "red" :"blue" } !important;
`;
```

in component :

```
        <StyledLink 
          href="#"
         >
           the red link
        </StyledLink>

        <StyledLink 
          href="/any"
         >
           the blue link
        </StyledLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason

the problem was ""

when I add "" to the code It works perfectly....

```
 a[href*="${props => props.currentHeader}"] {
    color: red;
  }
```